# No matching records found (ODBC -2028) in SAP DI Service Call

Tags: sapb1

When I try to make a new service call I get a `No matching records found (ODBC -2028)` here is my code:

```
Dim sC = company.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oServiceCalls)
sC.CustomerCode = recordSet.Fields.Item(2).Value Logging(sC.CustomerCode)
sC.Subject = recordSet.Fields.Item(3).Value
sC.Description = recordSet.Fields.Item(5).Value
sC.InternalSerialNum = recordSet.Fields.Item(11).Value
sC.ItemCode = recordSet.Fields.Item(11).Value
Dim ret = sC.Add()
If ret <> 0 Then company.GetLastError(ErrCode, ErrMsg)
  Logging("Error in service call: " + ErrCode.ToString() + " : " + ErrMsg)
End If
```

Every value is valid.  When I remove the InternalSerialNum line. it is working. The InetrnalSerialNum is valid too.  And on the other machine, this code is working.

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: The OSRN (serial numbers) table has three columns that could be considered keys: DistNumber, SysNumber and AbsEntry. Are you passing it the right value? I'd guess it should be the DistNumber value. Does that OSRN record have the same item code?

Comment: I checked it. I added the DistNumber and this is the same what is mine InternalSerialNum. (I tried the SysNumber and AbsEntry but I get the similar error.) Can I see what SQL command running?

Comment: Well. We used similar InternalSerialNum at two company, and when I was trying to insert it I tried with the other one.